# How to create a no overlapping Validation for an integer range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a validation for a period so one period cannot overlap another period. At this point I have the period that has an integer range from 1-52 (as in weeks 1-52).

I have the validation working if the period is 20-40 and It will error if the new period lays in that range.

However if the period is from 33-8 it wont throw an error when another period overlaps it.

How can I do this?

```
class Period < ApplicationRecord

 validate :start_week_cannot_overlap_period
 validate :finish_week_cannot_overlap_period
 validates :start_week, inclusion: { in: (1..52), message: '%<value>s must be a valid week number' }
 validates :finish_week, inclusion: { in: (1..52), message: '%<value>s must be a valid week number' }

 scope :overlapping, ->(integer) do
  where 'start_week <= :integer and finish_week >= :integer', integer: integer
 end

 def start_week_cannot_overlap_period
   return unless Period.overlapping(start_week).any?
   errors.add(:start_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
 end

 def finish_week_cannot_overlap_period
   return unless Period.overlapping(finish_week).any?
   errors.add(:finish_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
 end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you just need to also validate that `finish_week > start_week`?

Comment: It needs to work when finish_week is smaller or greater than start_week. as the period could be weeks 9-32 and 33-8

Comment: I think this is ActiveRecord related, use of ActiveAdmin is incidental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 scope :overlapping, ->(integer) do
   where '(start_week <= :integer and finish_week >= :integer) or ' \
         '(start_week > finish_week and (start_week <= :integer or finish_week >= :integer))', 
         integer: integer
 end
```